# wraping a native library that implements a callback in c#

Tags: c#, events, delegates, callback

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C# .NET 3.5 class that provides access to a native library. The library has a Register method that allows the user to specify a callback that will be activated on some event. I've provided a C# implementation below:

```
internal class MyLibHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid { /*...*/ }

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    public delegate void OnSomeEventDelegate (FOO foo, IntPtr user);

    [DllImport("MyLib.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public static extern bool MyLib_Register(MyLibHandle handle, OnSomeEventDelegate callback, IntPtr user);
}

public class MyWrappedLib : IDisposable
{
    private MyLibHandle handle_;

    private event EventHandler<OnSomeEventArgs> some_event_int_;

    public event EventHandler<OnSomeEventArgs> SomeEvent
    {
        add
        {
            if (some_event_int_ == null)
            {
                if (!NativeMethods.MyLib_Register(handle_, ReceivedSomeEvent, IntPtr.Zero))
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
            some_event_int_ += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            some_event_int_ -= value;
            if (some_event_int_ == null)
            {
                if (!NativeMethods.MyLib_DeRegister(handle_, -1))
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReceivedSomeEvent(FOO foo, IntPtr user)
    {
        OnSomeEvent(new OnSomeEventArgs() { foo = foo });
    }

    protected virtual void OnBeacon(OnSomeEventArgs args)
    {
        EventHandler<OnSomeEventArgs> evt = some_event_int_;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(this, args);
    }
}
```

This works, but I get a couple ominous sounding warnings

```
warning : CA1065 : Microsoft.Design : 'MyWrappedLib.SomeEvent.add(EventHandler<OnSomeEventArgs>)' creates an exception of type 'Win32Exception', an exception type that should not be raised in this type of method.

warning : CA2122 : Microsoft.Security : 'MyWrappedLib.SomeEvent.add(EventHandler<OnSomeEventArgs>)' calls into 'Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()' which has a LinkDemand. By making this call, 'Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()' is indirectly exposed to user code.
```

What is the recommended way of dealing with this situation? Should I create a method to handle the event subscriptions instead of the traditional add; remove; accessors?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For event accessors, following exception types are allowed:

- **System.InvalidOperationException** and all derivatives (including
  **System.ObjectDisposedException**)
- **System.NotSupportedException** and all derivatives
- **ArgumentException** and derivatives

Why would native method return false?
Would it be connected with some external conditions,
or it is result of invalid parameters passed?

So I would wrap Win32Exception as inner for InvalidOperationException,
or ArgumentException, depending on your situation.

Second warning (CA2122) is about security - 
it warns that Marshal.GetLastWin32Error performs security checks,
and your code doesn't. This security check is performed only once,
on first call. All calls after that are not verified for access rights,
for performance reasons. So in theory, first call could be made by
trusted user, and all further calls would not be restricted.

You need to either decorate your event handler with following attribute:

> [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]

(it will check that code has rights to invoke managed code)
or suppress this warning, if security is no concern in your application.

Details are greatly explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151738/can-someone-explain-this-linkdemand-warning-when-subclassing-a-windows-control).